# How to drop body of a request after checking headers in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I want to check the header of the request whether it contains a certain header or not before continuing with the body. For example, I want to check whether a multipart/form-data contains `"Authorization"` in the header or not. If it is not then there is no need to continue with uploading the multipart body which are generally quite large for file uploading.

Does servlet allow you to do this? I have tried to search on google randomly but there is no luck. Here is the code i try in my servlet but it still continues with recieving the body before this `doPost` method is called. It seems that the stream is fully received before the servlet is invoked.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    if (request.getHeader("Authorization") == null) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        out.println("Status: " + HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED + " - UNAUTHORIZED");
        return;
    }
    // ... the rests
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the limitation of HTTP. You can't send a response when the request hasn't been read fully to end.

Comment: I remembered talking to a friend that there are programs which help to block the attacks by checking the header and determine whether the connection should be dropt before the body is fully received. I just wonder that if this is the limitation for HTTP then it means that attacking a website by sending large bandwith is possible, right?

Comment: The Servlet API doesn't offer any facilities to drop the HTTP connection.

Answer (score 1):

RFC 2616 says:

> An HTTP/1.1 (or later) client sending a message-body SHOULD monitor the network connection for an error status while it is transmitting the request. If the client sees an error status, it SHOULD immediately cease transmitting the body.

So I disagree, this is not a HTTP limitation but a servlet one.

Comment: Do you know if clients actually support this?