# Does Spring Framework support streaming mode in multipart requests

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, apache-commons

I coulnd't find any indication in [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/mvc.html) that it support read of files in streaming mode in its object MultipartHttpServletRequest that handle multipart requests.

 
in similar way that is possible in [Apache Commons framework](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html).

 
is it supported in Spring at all?

Comment: What do you mean by "streaming mode"?

Comment: I mean that the request is not sent completely to the server when the application want to read the files, instead the server can control the request and read the files of it one by one. To be able to deal with extremely large size requests

Comment: You will need to rethink about uploading large file strategy. You might have to write a client which splits the large file and a servlet which combines them after getting all fragments. BTW, server can never control the request. It has to fully accept the request no matter what (even if someone try to attack it).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have a look [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-multipart-resolver). Your Spring API is far too old. Also, the Streaming mode has nothing to do with Spring. It is the ability of your servlet container or your server. Most server now support the streaming mode. Servlet will start performing the request as soon as it got the header from your request. You can continue to send out the stream of your request body (e.g. multipart data). However, the parsing can only be performed completely when the request is sent fully. This is the same as Apache Common FileUpload.

Alternatively, you can write a controller using Spring annotation. Spring will inject the ServletRequest if you add that as one of your method controller arugument. After that, you can use Apache FileUpload to do multipart parsing.

You can not do selective parsing since the request must be fully sent to server no matter what. It is the limit of Http. I asked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528778/how-to-drop-body-of-a-request-after-checking-headers-in-servlet) a few day ago.

Comment: I don't think that the request MUST be fully sent to the server. See my response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836760/is-there-a-way-to-get-raw-http-request-stream-from-java-servlet-handler/4552280#4552280

Comment: @Spiderman I don't see any explanation in your post. The reason I said that because I have done experiment on it using debugger. Servlet thread starts running even if the stream has not been fully sent, but the headers have. FileUpload API starts reading the stream and write it to temporarily files. Before the next instruction can be executed, the stream must be fully recieved. Otherwise FileUpload will throw an exception and remove previously uploaded data.

Comment: I was doing the experience using plain HTTPServletRequest and not any Spring wrapper that extends it. I checked using HTTP sniffer and came to conclusion that as long as I didn't read from the request's stream, the client side didn't send the data to the server side so I as an application programmer that run on a web-server can control the delivering of the HTTP request

Comment: I have done the samething as you describe. I submit a file using html form POST. The stream I captured has the content attached to it. I noticed that if I upload a large file, my servlet will not response reponse util the web browser send the request fully. So my conclusion is that the stream is fully sent even if you did not do anything with it.

Comment: Same thing happened with uploading from a simple multipart/form-data posted using URLConnection.

Comment: your servlet may not response until the whole request arrive to the server, BUT during this time, if the client sent large request with many items/files, the server can start handling them, do its business logic and persist those files to the DB during the time that the data keep coming from the client - this is a performance optimization that can be done using the HTTPRequest wrapper of apache common but not using Spring's HTTPRequest wrapper. That's why I think that you are wrong.

Comment: Maybe my english is not clear but that is exactly what I mean. I said that the complete parsing can only be done when the request is sent fully. Server can parse during recieving request and handling them but it cannot parse those that hasn't been arrive or ask it to arrive earlier than the others. So you cannnot handle selectively or just receive the request you want. You will have to recieve them all. And you also mention that if you do not get the request stream, client won't sent it. I think this is wrong. It will be sent unless client terminate it.

Comment: I think I must misunderstand your streaming mode to chunk streaming mode, which is the ability of server. I think Spring handles the parsing in streaming mode internally before it can inject the request to your servlet if you decide to use Spring multipart parser via annotation. You give up have the ability to handle parts of request during the recieving of whole request but it does not mean Spring does not handle them internally that way. But if you just use Spring for injecting Servlet request, and the use FileUpload to handle your parsing then you should be able to handle them on a fly.

Comment: I apologise for my misunderstanding about streaming mode. I think we have pretty much the same understanding of the servlet request now. Please keep me update if you know whether you can get Spring mulitpart parser to hand you over the control during the recieving. It will be valuable for me too.

Comment: I look into the source code of CommonsMultipartResolver. It uses Apache FileUpload to handle with request. http://kickjava.com/src/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartResolver.java.htm